# BaseAdapter crashes on notifyDataSetChanged update?

Tags: java, android, listview

When trying to update my array adapter upon a network request, the program crashes with `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference`, I have seen other posts with the same time but every method I try seems to just result in an error, the same crashing bug most likely.

Of course the title says, I am using `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update my lists.

Here is my code that I am using

```
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    public ArrayList<String> aContacts = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ListView contacts;
    public CustomAdapter customAdapter;

    // User Setup Defaults
    String server = "https://xxxxxxxx";
    String suser = "xxxxxx";
    String spass = "xxxxxx";

    String sreq;

    public void getContacts() {
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = server+"/xxxxxx/?username="+suser+"&password="+spass+"&getcontacts=yes";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        Log.v(TAG, "I recieved: " + response);
                        try {
                            JSONArray parseContacts = new JSONArray(response);

                            for (int x = 0; x < parseContacts.length(); x++) {
                                JSONArray array = (JSONArray) parseContacts.get(x);
                                for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++){
                                    // print: array.get(j).toString();
                                }
                                aContacts.add(array.get(0).toString());

                                customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // ERROR IS HERE

                            }
                        }catch(JSONException e) {
                            Log.v(TAG, "Error: "+e);
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Oops, an error occurred");
            }
        });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView contacts = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contacts);

        getContacts();

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
        contacts.setAdapter(customAdapter);



        contacts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object o = contacts.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),aContacts.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return aContacts.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row,null);

            TextView username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            username.setText(aContacts.get(position));

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Im trying to parse JSON data and that works fine, and I add the results to an array and it would appear something like this `{"one", "two", "three"}`, but it doesnt seem to have to do with that and just crashes with that error on runtime. I have struggled at this forever now, if someone could give me some code that is the working version would be really nice but probably wouldnt happen, so just reference the issue please, or whatever you can do to help, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that's actually where the problem is?

Comment: Also, you should remove the global `contacts` variable. You aren't using it and it'll cause other problems in the future if you accidentally reference it.

Comment: I honestly think it'd be easier for you to switch to using RecyclerView instead of ListView - I'm willing to bet your problems will be solved indirectly. It would also encourage you to recycle your views, which you are not currently doing (implementation of adapter's getView).

Comment: Additionally, you must implement the adapter's getItem() method. That wouldn't solve this exact issue imo, but would prevent introducing upcoming issues.

Comment: Finally, I'm sort of guessing here cause you haven't included a full stack-trace and the activity_main layout xml -- but it looks like `findViewById(R.id.contacts)` resolves to null. Are you sure there's a `ListView` down the view hierarchy you've specified in `activity_main.xml`?